# Click and drop events to update a calculation

Tags: c#, jquery, ms-access

At the moment in my application I have an arrangement of passengers located in different rows on a transporting device (so I have a database storing their locations and weights). My objective is to be able to drag and drop those passengers to different locations and update the final centre of gravity for this device.  So I am not sure how to attach the data from this data table into some sort of draggable and droppable event to trigger the recalculation of the center of gravity. Can anyone give me a suggestion on what concept should I be looking at for this kind of action?

Comment: By the way, My data is stored in microsoft access ^

Comment: A DataTable is not a UI object, so you need to attach an indentifier (like the ID of the passenger) to whatever UI control you are using. All Objects have a Tag property which might work to store it.